# Toad for Oracle - changing formatting on DBMS Output window

Tags: toad

On the DBMS Output window for Toad v11, how can you change the DBMS Output font and color? I've looked all over in the options but I'm unable to find where it's possible it change this. It's way too small by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Options -> Oracle -> General. About halfway down is a box titled "DBMS Output" with a button inside titled "Font". Click this and it will open a new dialog box allowing you to modify the font type, size, color, etc.

Comment: THANK YOU, I looked all over and couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Found it at the same location in my version 9.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Toad 13.x, it is View > Toad Options > Data Grids > Visual. In the Styles section, you can drill into Edit to change the font and size.

Answer (score 0):

please select View Menu tab from the taskbar >> Toad option >>  Oracle Dropdown >> General>> DBMS output click the button Font and you can change from there.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

For Toad 13, the DMBS Output settings are at View > Toad Options > Oracle > General.